# Is it possible to clear the 'program installed' icons at the top notification bar?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, notifications, updates

When you perform an update of an installed program, the top notification bar displays a 'downloading' icon.

When it is downloaded, it displays a 'successfully updated' icon.

**Is there a way to clear these 'successfully updated' icons?**

I found no other way than to pull down the notification bar, and click the installed notification messages, but this always starts the updated program.

I was just wondering if you can clear these icons without having to start the program.

*A minor thing, I know, but once I get a question like that in my head...*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Towards the top of your notification bar there should be a <kbd>Clear</kbd> button. Click this to clear your notifications (this will clear all pending notifications, not just application installed/updated ones).

Comment: Would you believe I never noticed that button there ? It's to the right of the name of my provider and I just skipped that line completely in me viewing the list :)

Comment: Sometimes it's the simplest things we just don't notice!